# Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 86965 > 65536)

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps

*Update: After running ProGuard to lessen my resources, it seems that ProGuard may be deleting important code:
Erorr: Could not find method android() for arguments [build_7b52k4yyeks9l2efdeec28zeo$_run_closure2@6cc7c31f] on root project 'Google maps Demo' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
Updated build.gradle code:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization for only
            // your project's release build type.
            minifyEnabled true

            // Enables resource shrinking, which is performed by the
            // Android Gradle plugin.
            shrinkResources true

            // Includes the default ProGuard rules files that are packaged with
            // the Android Gradle plugin. To learn more, go to the section about
            // R8 configuration files.
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                    'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I'm using android studio to implement Google maps api using Android's Coding's tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eiexkzCI8m8). I'm getting this error as a "D8 errors" and two errors in my Java compiler.
Error #1:"Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete"

Error #2: "Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: null, Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 86965 > 65536)"

Anyone see the problem?

Here is my java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;

        LatLng Brockton = new LatLng(42.0895988,-70.9798322);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Brockton).title("Brockton"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Brockton));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Solution:**

Open your app level build.gradle file. and simply write in android->defaultConfig-> `multiDexEnabled true`

**Code For Better Understanding.**

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a fault in your code, it is because of your dependency on Google Maps.

This adds a lot of methods to your app, passing the limit of 64k per dex file. There are two solutions:

Use MultiDex: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex
Android Studio will generate multiple dex files, so the limit is not reached.

Use ProGuard removing unused methods: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code
Methods which are not called, are not added to your dex file. This is, combined with obfuscating, always a good idea.

Comment: I tried to first Use ProGuard to shrink the code and its returns this error:
Could not find method android() for arguments [build_7b52k4yyeks9l2efdeec28zeo$_run_closure2@6cc7c31f] on root project 'Google maps Demo' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Answer (score 1):

write:

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

in build.gradle(app) file

Answer (score 1):

in android>app>build.gradle add in defaultConfig:

```
defaultConfig {
    
    multiDexEnabled true

    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).